# C - Hooking Internet Explorer download function

Tags: internet-explorer, function, download, hook

In order to increase security on a new computer, I want to write a little software to hook internet explorer and display a password prompt every time someone tries to download a file (that is in order to prevent my little cousins from downloading all kinds of toolbars and other rubbish).

I have experience and knowledge of hooking and methods and such, my question is, what is the routine/function/method in which internet explorer downloads a file?

Hooking CreateFile is not an option because the browser downloads and caches stuff all the time. Ss there a function that triggers the Run/Save/Cancel prompt? In my searches I only found `TriggerFileDownload`, but I don't know if the browser itself uses it.

Comment: Why not hook CreateFile after all and look at the extension? The browser won't cache .zip, .exe and so on.

Comment: The Run/Save/Cancel prompt probably has its own window class so hooking CreateWindow or CreateWindowEx and looking for that specific class should do the trick. Will be very version specific though!

Comment: @rasmus Thanks for the Idea, Ill try checking the extension.